# Using Pyqt4 to download thousands of PDF's from URL

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt4

I am trying to ideally download thousands of PDF from a given website.  However, for some reason it won't even download 100 PDF's.  I am not sure why.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import StringIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Foo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)    

        self.count  = -1
        text_file = open("input.txt", "r")
        self.params = text_file.read().split('\n')
        self.url    = 'http://www.asdfasdfasdf.com/Property.aspx?mode=details&pin={0}'

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        #self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        #self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.on_mapper_mapped)

        for i in range(100):
            grabber = QWebView()
            grabber.loadFinished.connect(self.mapper.map)

            self.mapper.setMapping(grabber, i)
            #self.tabWidget.addTab(grabber, "opener {0}".format(str(i)))

            grabber.loadFinished.emit(True)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_mapper_mapped(self, gNumber):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < len(self.params):
            #gParam = self.params[self.count]
            gParam = self.params[self.count]

            opener = self.mapper.mapping(gNumber)
            opener.load(QUrl(self.url.format(gParam)))
            printer = QPrinter()
            #setting format
            printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
            #export file as c:\tem_pdf.pdf
            PIDString = gParam[:2] + '-' + gParam[2:4] + '-' + gParam[4:7] + '-' + gParam[7:10] + '-' + gParam[10:14]
            printer.setOutputFileName(PIDString + '.pdf')
            def convertIt():
                opener.print_(printer)

            QObject.connect(opener, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
            print str(self.count) + ' of ' + str(len(self.params))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Foo()
    #main.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit
```

Ideally I would like to add a footer as well but it bugs out if I try to do that.  Input.txt has 100 numbers ( just for test, I need it to work on 85000).  It works on real small numbers like 5 or 10 but won't do 100.  Is there a limit to the QwebView instance?  Should I manage that in order to make it work?

When I run this code for 100 PDF, it will print out 20 PDFS.  If i Change the range to something smaller than 100, it will have duplicate PDF's but certainly more than 20.

Also, I get this error:

> qpainter::begin: returned false

Comment: what happens when it "does not work for big numbers"? messages? symptoms?

Comment: also, maybe you run into serverside throttling/antispam. have you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

I think since you are trying to make a "PyQt Application" you should firstly make use of what it offers your.

Try have some look into it [QNetworkAccessMAnager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to have control of all your requests and all else, [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html), [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html).

It will even take care of your threads and have your parallelism as desired. It won't freeze your app while it's being downloaded.

Have a small look into this code of mine. It doesn't do exactly what you want but is kinda a really good filtered example for what you need to have all set up.

```
# Subclass QNetworkAccessManager Here
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest


class NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):

    signal_add_image = pyqtSignal()
    dialog = None
    download_finished = False
    message_buffer = None
    reply = None

    def __init__(self):
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        self.reply = self.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("")))

    # Save image data in QByteArray buffer to the disk (google_image_logo.png
    # in the same directory)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def slot_finished(self):
        image_file = QFile("resources/browser_images/image_required_browser")
        if image_file.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite):
            image_file.write(self.message_buffer)
            image_file.close()
            self.signal_add_image.emit()
            # QMessageBox.information(None, "Hello!", "File has been saved!")
        else:
            pass
            # QMessageBox.critical(None, "Hello!", "Error saving file!")
        self.download_finished = True
        self.dialog.close()

    # Append current data to the buffer every time readyRead() signal is
    # emitted
    @pyqtSlot()
    def slot_read_data(self):
        self.message_buffer += self.reply.readAll()

    def request_image(self, url, progress_bar, dialog):
        self.reply.deleteLater()
        self.download_finished = False
        self.dialog = dialog
        self.message_buffer = QByteArray()
        url = QUrl(url)
        req = QNetworkRequest(url)
        req.setRawHeader(b'User-Agent',
                                    b'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36')
        self.reply = self.get(req)
        self.reply.readyRead.connect(self.slot_read_data)
        self.reply.finished.connect(self.slot_finished)
        self.reply.downloadProgress.connect(progress_bar)

    def get_reply(self):
        return self.reply

    def done(self):
        return self.download_finished

    def set_reply(self, reply):
        self.reply = reply

    def del_reply(self):
        self.reply.deleteLater()

NETWORK_ACCESS_MANAGER = NetworkAccessManager()
```

Hope it brings you some light ")